# Arrrow Flight to send RecordBatch Stream Bytpe Array as batch over python Rest Api Response

Tags: python, pyarrow, dremio

I  have  a  result set as a stream of Arrow record batches,i   have used  reader.read_chunk() to  get  the  batchs ,i   have  pushed  the  batches  to  batch  array  and  convert  it  to  bytearray  as  response .for  that  here  is  the  code

```
def getBatchStreambytes(_):
   reader = client.do_get(flight_info.endpoints[0].ticket, options)
            print('[INFO] Reading query results from Dremio Server ')
            batches = [] 
            while True:
                     try:
                            batch, metadata = reader.read_chunk()
                            print(batch.num_rows)
                            batches.append(batch)

                except Exception as exception:
                        break

        data = pa.Table.from_batches(batches)
        sink = pa.BufferOutputStream()
        writer = pa.RecordBatchStreamWriter(sink, data.schema)
        writer.write_table(data)
        writer.close()
        #print(reader.read_pandas())

        return  sink.getvalue().to_pybytes()
```

as  API  response  taking  more  time for  each  batches ,how  its  possible  to  send  batch as  response so  that    api  will respond with  iterated batch ,how  i  can  send  chunks  of  batch.
Here  us  screenshots  of  List  of  Batches  i  recived  from flight  server
[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking.  You are currently reading data one batch at a time.  You are asking how to send the batch as a response.  However, I do not know you mean.  Is this some kind of HTTP server and you want to send a response?  Are you writing a flight server?  Is `getBatchStreambytes` a standard method of some library?  I'm afraid it is not very clear to me what you are doing.

Comment: i  want  to  send  response  as  chunk  in  api  response  as   if the query has over 50 million rows or so  then  in  that  case  api  tooks  2 -3  min  resonse  time.how  i  can  send  chunk  of  batch  as  response  so  atlest  even  10  record  in batch  i  can  get   10  record  as  response .I  am  not  writing  any  flight  server  ,i  am  using  dremio  which  is  already  flight  enabled  server